# Error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 servlet y tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

Amigos me sale este error al subir mi proyecto al apache tomcat

utilizo apache tomcat 7.0.67
IDE: Netbeans 8.2 
con java plataform jdk 1.8 
run java EE 6 Web
 su ayuda por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tienes definido en tu proyecto un JDK  de version mayor

Cambia la configuración de tu Netbeans a 1.8

Abre el archivo:

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans <VERSION>\etc\netbeans.conf
```

Cambia el valor de `netbeans_jdkhome`

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<VERSION JDK>"
```

en tu caso sería a el valor del JDK 1.8, revisa tu versión adecuada, esta debe estar instalada:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102"
```